# Can I build React Native CLI in a project with Expo-CLI?

Tags: react-native, expo

I need some help, I'm in a React Native project with Expo, the build is always done using expo, but the last builds we made for Android made the system strange with some bugs and slowness, I wanted to do a test to verify if the problem is the build that expo performs, then I tried to build using React Native-cli and a gradlew version error appears, the question is: can I build using React Native cli in a project with expo?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, you can build your project with the React Native CLI by removing the Expo-managed workflow and all Expo dependencies from your project. However, this process can be complex and time-consuming. Therefore, I wouldn't recommend doing it solely to test if the issue is related to Expo builds. Instead, consider ejecting from Expo if you intend to fully transition away from Expo and its managed workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I will need to test by removing the expo from the project, how could I do to remove the expo from the project?